# How to write the regexp to accept infinite numbers?

Tags: javascript

I have one regexp which is finding only 2 digit numbers. I'm trying with `\#break:[0-9][0-9]\s\minutes` this regexp. It has only 2 digits. How I can rewrite this to detect any number even it 5 or 6 digits.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) is always useful. Specifically search for "quantifiers" from the Special Characters table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\d+/` should do the trick.

"d" is the symbol for digits and "+" tells it to accept one or more.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `d+` as Kevin said: `\#break:\d+\s\minute`

Or if you exactly know how many digits should be found, just use `\#break:\d{1,5}\s\minute`, which will catch digits from 1 to 5.